# My email template shows HTML in its excerpt on Gmail

Tags: html, email, html-email

I've never seen this before, but my email template, when displayed in Gmail (ostensibly other clients too?), has HTML in its excerpt, like:

**John Smith sent you a message** *width="155" height="55" title="Welcome" style="display: inline; float: none;"...*

I've used bold for the email subject, and the italics is the excerpt.

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong? The whole template is below - I've just thrown in some dummy copy for title etc cause that's generated by PHP.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
<title>
    Test title
</title>
</head>
<body style="width: 100% !important; min-width: 100%; -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%; color: #ffffff; font-family: 'Helvetica', 'Arial', sans-serif; font-weight: normal; text-align: left; line-height: 19px; font-size: 14px; margin: 0; padding: 0;">
<table class="body" style="border-spacing: 0; border-collapse: collapse; vertical-align: top; text-align: left; height: 100%; width: 100%; color: #ffffff; font-family: 'Helvetica', 'Arial', sans-serif; font-weight: normal; line-height: 19px; font-size: 14px; background: #f1f1f1; margin: 0; padding: 0;" bgcolor="#ffffff">
<tbody>
<tr style="vertical-align: top; text-align: left; padding: 0;" align="left">
    <td class="center" align="center" valign="top" style="word-break: break-word; -webkit-hyphens: auto; -moz-hyphens: auto; hyphens: auto; border-collapse: collapse !important; vertical-align: top; text-align: center; color: #222222; font-family: 'Helvetica', 'Arial', sans-serif; font-weight: normal; line-height: 19px; font-size: 14px; margin: 0; padding: 30px 0px;">
         <center style="width: 100%; min-width: 580px;">
        <table class="row header" style="border-spacing: 0; border-collapse: collapse; vertical-align: top; text-align: left; width: 100%; position: relative; background: transparent; padding: 0px;" bgcolor="transparent">
        <tbody>
        <tr style="vertical-align: top; text-align: left; padding: 0;" align="left">
            <td class="center" align="center" style="word-break: break-word; -webkit-hyphens: auto; -moz-hyphens: auto; hyphens: auto; border-collapse: collapse !important; vertical-align: top; text-align: center; color: #222222; font-family: 'Helvetica', 'Arial', sans-serif; font-weight: normal; line-height: 19px; font-size: 14px; margin: 0; padding: 0;" valign="top">
                 <center style="width: 100%; min-width: 580px;">
                <table class="container" style="border-spacing: 0; border-collapse: collapse; vertical-align: top; text-align: inherit; width: 580px; background: transparent; margin: 0 auto; padding: 0;" bgcolor="white">
                <tbody>
                <tr style="vertical-align: top; text-align: left; padding: 0;" align="left">
                    <td class="wrapper last" style="word-break: break-word; -webkit-hyphens: auto; -moz-hyphens: auto; hyphens: auto; border-collapse: collapse !important; vertical-align: top; text-align: left; position: relative; color: #222222; font-family: 'Helvetica', 'Arial', sans-serif; font-weight: normal; line-height: 19px; font-size: 14px; margin: 0; padding: 0 35px border-style: solid; border-width: 1px 1px 0;" align="left" valign="top">
                        <table class="twelve columns" style="border-spacing: 0; border-collapse: collapse; vertical-align: top; text-align: left; width: 500px; margin: 0 auto; padding: 0;">
                        <tbody>
                        <tr style="vertical-align: top; text-align: left; padding: 0;" align="left">
                            <td class="six sub-columns last" style="vertical-align: middle; word-break: break-word; -webkit-hyphens: auto; -moz-hyphens: auto; hyphens: auto; border-collapse: collapse !important; min-width: 0px; width: 50%; color: #222222; font-family: 'Helvetica', 'Arial', sans-serif; font-weight: normal; line-height: 19px; font-size: 14px; margin: 0; padding: 20px 0px 35px; text-align: center;" align="right" valign="middle">
                                <a href="https://foo.com">
                                 <img src="https://app.foo.com/images/logo.png" alt="Foo" width="155" height="55" title="Foo" style="width: 155px; height: 55px; display: inline; float: none; outline: none; text-decoration: none; -ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic; max-width: 100%; clear: both; opacity: 1" align="none">
                                </a>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                </tbody>
                </table>
                </center>
            </td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
        </table>
        <table class="container" style="border-spacing: 0; border-collapse: collapse; vertical-align: top; text-align: inherit; width: 580px; margin: 0 auto; padding: 0;">
        <tbody>
        <tr style="vertical-align: top; text-align: left; padding: 0;" align="left">
            <td style="word-break: break-word; -webkit-hyphens: auto; -moz-hyphens: auto; hyphens: auto; border-collapse: collapse !important; vertical-align: top; text-align: left; color: #222222; font-family: 'Helvetica', 'Arial', sans-serif; font-weight: normal; line-height: 19px; font-size: 14px; margin: 0; padding: 0 50px; background: #ffffff;" align="left" valign="top" bgcolor="#ffffff">
                <table class="row" style="border-spacing: 0; border-collapse: collapse; vertical-align: top; text-align: left; width: 100%; position: relative; display: block; padding: 0px;">
                <tbody>
                <tr style="vertical-align: top; text-align: left; padding: 0;" align="left">
                    <td class="wrapper last" style="word-break: break-word; -webkit-hyphens: auto; -moz-hyphens: auto; hyphens: auto; border-collapse: collapse !important; vertical-align: top; text-align: left; position: relative; color: #222222; font-family: 'Helvetica', 'Arial', sans-serif; font-weight: normal; line-height: 19px; font-size: 14px; margin: 0; padding: 50px 0px;" align="left" valign="top">
                        <table class="twelve columns" style="border-spacing: 0; border-collapse: collapse; vertical-align: top; text-align: left; width: 500px; margin: 0 auto; padding: 0;">
                        <tbody>
                        <tr style="vertical-align: top; text-align: left; padding: 0;" align="left">
                            <td style="word-break: break-word; vertical-align: top; text-align: left; margin: 0px; padding: 0px 0px 20px; border-collapse: collapse !important;" align="left" valign="top">
                                <p style="text-align: center; color: #444444; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 18px; line-height: 27px; font-weight: 300; margin: 0px 0px 10px; padding: 0px;" align="center">
                                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
                                </p>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr style="vertical-align: top; text-align: left; padding: 0;" align="left">
                            <td style="word-break: break-word; vertical-align: top; text-align: left; margin: 0px; padding: 40px 0px 35px; border-collapse: collapse !important; border-top: 1px solid #cccccc; border-bottom: 1px solid #cccccc;" align="left" valign="top">
                                <p style="text-align: center; color: black; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 25px; line-height: 1.5; font-weight: 300; margin: 0px; padding: 0px;" align="center">
                                    Test title
                                </p>
                                <p style="text-align: center; color: #444444; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 14px; line-height: 19px; font-weight: 300; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; padding-top: 15px;" align="center">
                                    Test subtitle
                                </p>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr style="vertical-align: top; text-align: left; padding: 0;" align="left">
                            <td style="word-break: break-word; vertical-align: top; text-align: left; margin: 0px; padding: 30px 0px 0px; border-collapse: collapse !important; text-align: center;" align="center" valign="top">
                                <table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center">
                                    <tr>
                                        <td align="center" style="border-radius: 3px;" bgcolor="#17c68c">
                                            <a href="https://foo.com" target="_blank" style="font-size: 16px; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; color: #ffffff; text-decoration: none; text-decoration: none; padding: 15px 40px; border-bottom: 3px solid #149369; display: inline-block; font-weight: 300;">
                                                Test label
                                            </a>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                </table>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                </tbody>
                <!-- container end below -->
            </td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
        </table>
        </center>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td style="padding-top: 20px;">
        <p style="text-align: center; color: #444444; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 14px; line-height: 19px; font-weight: 300; margin: 0px 0px 10px; padding: 0px; padding-bottom: 45px;" align="center">
            From your friends at <a style="color: #17c68c;" href="https://foo.com">Foo</a>.
        </p>
    </td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hey there, can you please include your code so we can take a look. Will make it a lot easier to debug.

Comment: I've just added the whole code above. Hope it helps?

Comment: Odd, I can't replicate in Gmail or desktop Outlook 2013.
I did notice a couple of things that you could try though:      
   1. No Doctype was included. Maybe try adding that in?
   2. I found an un-closed table. Where the comment '<!-- container end below -->' is, either above or below that needs to be a closing table tag.

No idea if either of those will help, but best to give the Doctype a go at least and test again on your end.

Comment: I think that did it, actually! Putting a Doctype in seems like it did the trick. If you wanna put your comment as an answer, I'll give it a tick?

Comment: Awesome! Will do :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Odd, I can't replicate in Gmail or desktop Outlook 2013.

I did notice a couple of things that you could try though:

1. No Doctype was included. Maybe try adding that in?
2. I found an un-closed table. Where the comment '' is, either above or below that needs to be a closing
   table tag.

No idea if either of those will help, but best to give the Doctype a go at least and test again on your end.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously, you miss `<img` tag before your excerpt. Because this part: `width="155" height="55" title="Welcome" style="display: inline; float: none;"` is used for image styling.

Comment: It's definitely not that obvious. The image tag exists and is rendered correctly when actually reading the email - it's just the excerpt that's rendering markup.